# How can I call methods on items in a ReferenceQueue if type erasure has allowed me to only call Object() methods?

Tags: java, type-erasure, soft-references

I have a reference queue, declared as:

```
ReferenceQueue<MapChunk> rqueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
```

and I have some soft references constructed in the form of

```
SoftReference ref=new SoftReference<MapChunk>(ourChunk, rqueue);
```

As per the docs, `rqueue` is `ReferenceQueue<? extends MapChunk>`

I wish to call a handler on their garbage collection, which is why I put them into the queue. However, when I begin processing the queue from another thread, I retrieve the object from the queue via

```
Reference ref=rqueue.poll();
synchronized (chunks) {
    synchronized (MapDatabase.class) {
        chunks.put(ref.get().getPosition(), ref.get());
    }
}
```

My compiler errors indicate type erasure has occurred and I'm left with `ref.get()` being an object(due to the raw type of the queue). I can neither call methods on the object that I need nor can I pass it to a method that requires a `MapChunk` itself. Surely this impedes many uses of the reference queue, and I'm likely doing something wrong in that case. I am certain that I will only get `MapChunk` objects at runtime, so should I use a cast? Do something else? Not use the reference queue at all?

Edit: If I use `Reference<MapChunk> ref=rqueue.poll()` I get the following:

```
cannot convert from Reference<capture#1-of ? extends MapChunk> to Reference<MapChunk>
```

When I use `Reference<? extends MapChunk> ref=rqueue.poll();` the error on that line is resolved, but another error comes up when I try to use `ref`:

```
The method addMapChunk(Position, SoftReference<MapChunk>) in the type HashMap<Position,SoftReference<MapChunk>> is not applicable for the arguments (Position, capture#3-of ? extends MapChunk).
```

Edit: I guess it was simply a buggy error message as the type did convert properly when another bug was fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want type erasure, don't erase the type.

```
Reference<? extends MapChunk> ref = rqueue.poll();
MapChunk mc = ref.get();
```

Comment: +1 It was that simple that I missed? I was under the impression that the type was erased at the time the queue was created and used. Interesting first sentence, by the way.

Comment: @hexafraction I like to keep things simple ;)

Comment: Actually, there's a minor issue still. If you see the edit I get a very odd failed attempt to convert from `Reference<capture#1-of ? extends MapChunk>`, if that's even valid syntax. Changing it to `Reference<? extends MapChunk>` causes more issues that I've edited into my question.

Comment: @hexafraction Sorry, you have to use `? extends MapChunk`

Comment: I get the odd malformed message when I do that. It appears that it was eclipse yielding a malformed message over another small typo. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Type erasure will still occur. Specifying a bounded type parameter for the generic Reference (instead of treating it as a raw/unbounded type) allows the compiler to treat ref.get() as returning the desired type instead of Object.

Comment: @BuzzKillington True.  Type erasure occurs at runtime, but not compile time in this case.